# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator Not running - It Starts and then throws Error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to install and run Cosmos DB Emulator on my machine but it is not letting me to connect to Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. When I run the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, it shows the "Started" notification and then opened a page in browser but the page is not loaded. I am tired of doing everything which I have found on google.

Here is the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator Error:

[image]

And when the page is opened on link https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html, the Firefox browser shows "Unable to connect"

[image]

The strange thing is, when I installed it on another machine, it ran there without any issue.

Comment: "doing everything which I have found on google." without knowing what these are, you are likely to get the same suggestions here.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling it? Agree on comment above. What other steps did you try?

Comment: Have you gone through the Emulator Troubleshooting page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting

Comment: I have uninstalled/reinstalled it. I have switched off firewall completely and then run. I have tried to run Cosmos DB Emulator through command line by giving AllowNetworkAccess, NoFirewall, changing DirectPorts (for each emulator) and port (for running the Cosmos DB page on localhost). Restarting system and reset cosmos data were done multiple times.

Comment: No Suggestion! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After full of 3 hectic days, I have successfully run Cosmos DB Emulator. Here is the work around.

1. Shut down Azure Cosmos DB Emulator
2. I tried to run lodctr /R in command line by running it as "Run as Administrator", it threw an error: "Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2"
3. Found a solution for the lodctr /R error which is to run another command as below:
   "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"
   It will install ASP.NET (2.0.50727). Here is the link: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2016/04/unable-to-rebuild-performance-counter-setting-from-system-backup-store/
4. Then again run the command lodctr /R, it sets the counter
5. Then start Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and it will run.

Comment: Why does step 3 work? Is there some web page discussing this?

Comment: I have just edited my answer and provided the link from where I found the solution. However it does not discuss why it was throwing that error. In fact I had successfully installed and run Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on another system, even when I ran lodctr /R command there, it threw the same error as above although that system did not need to run lodctr /R or aspnet_regiis.exe -i commands there.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this constantly, I realised I was shutting down my pc before stopping the emulator. Once I started stopping the emulator before shutdown, this issue went away for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 ports the emulator runs on out of the box: `10251,10252,10253,10254`. You can confirm this by typing:

```
.\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe -h
```

And you'll see:

> /DirectPorts= Comma-separated list of 4 ports to use for direct connectivity. Default is 10251,10252,10253,
> 10254.

What tends to be my issue is that the emulator is still running on one of the above ports but `.\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /Shutdown` doesn't effectively stop the process.
To combat this, I search to see which port is active:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> netstat -ano | findstr :10251
PS C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> netstat -ano | findstr :10252
PS C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> netstat -ano | findstr :10253
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10253        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       27772
```

And then I stop that process:

```
stop-process 27772 // this is using powershell but that's unimportant
```

Then I can start the emulator again without issue:

```
.\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe
```